# Get into website

Tags: php, curl

I used below code to get into a website.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'www.g.com');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "aa:qq");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

But i m getting blank page.Whre am i going wrong?

Comment: Well, what does $info contain?

Answer (score 1):

You don't `echo` or `print`  anything.

Try `echo $info;` or `echo $output;`

Comment: @bgff : I'm not Dan, but still, depending on the level of security the site have you can access it. You should go [on this page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) and look for `https` and `ssl`.